# How can I use an import statement in the Jest test file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, ts-jest, babel-jest

I'm trying to integrate the jest to my current react project. It's a typescript project. I followed the **ts-jest** instructions and configured the jest. If I run simple test cases, It works well. When I add the following line or any import line the terminal gives me an error.

```
import React from 'react';
```

When I run the **"npm test"** command, the terminal gives me the following error. The error source is the sample test file. *(test.tsx)*

**SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.**

I tried lots of different solutions but none of them worked.

**My tsconfig.json file is;**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "global.d.ts",
    "test"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "coverage",
    "node_modules",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

**babel.config.js is;**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
}
```

**jest.config.js is;**

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/src/(?!serviceWorker)"],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      diagnostics: false
    }
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|css|less)$": "<rootDir>/src/test/resourceFileMock.ts",
  }
};
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Hey @cinaarss, could you please add details of `tsconfig.json` file ?

Comment: Hi @prabhat-mishra, I added my tsconfig.json file.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

could you try with these values in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es6"],
"jsx":"preserve",
"strict": true
```

Remove below values:

```
"module": "esnext",
```